# Render WebGL in Xfvb

Tags: webgl, xvfb

I want to headless test WebGL code using Xvfb. Does anybody know how to do that?

I have 2 machines - both running Ubuntu. One with NVidia card and one with ATI:

The NVidia machine:

```
ipmi:~ $>xvfb-run glxinfo
name of display: :455
display: :455  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
...

ipmi:~ $>xvfb-run glxgears
3725 frames in 5.0 seconds = 741.884 FPS
3840 frames in 5.0 seconds = 767.310 FPS
4080 frames in 5.0 seconds = 814.811 FPS
4120 frames in 5.0 seconds = 821.859 FPS
```

The ATI machine:

```
shaka:~ $>xvfb-run glxinfo
name of display: :99
display: :99  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4

shaka:~ $>xvfb-run glxgears
4326 frames in 5.0 seconds = 865.095 FPS
4343 frames in 5.0 seconds = 868.540 FPS
```

Even if shaka supports direct rendering using Mesa, I can't get a WebGL context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With modern X11, you would be better off ignoring `Xvfb` and using the `dummy` display driver.  See the "Additional notes" at http://www.x.org/wiki/XorgTesting for information about using it (you would presumably specify a custom `xorg.conf` with the necessary `Device` section).  http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/Xdummy is another way to use the dummy driver.

Comment: Looks good but sadly, the dummy driver doesn't support WebGL as well :(

Comment: Related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040370/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu