# How do I enable WebGL in headless chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, webgl, ubuntu-14.04, nightwatch.js

How do I enable webgl or install webgl in headless chrome in Ubuntu 14? I tried installing libosmesa6, but that did not help.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I want to use webgl to work with headless chrome and selenium tests? I am using nightwatch to run the tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me to get chrome to use osmesa

```
sudo apt-get install libosmesa
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOSMesa.so.6 /opt/google/chrome/libosmesa.so
google-chrome --no-first-run --user-data-dir=~/chrome-stuff --use-gl=osmesa
```

Warning: When running with osmesa the entire page is rendered with osmesa making it pretty slow. So, if there are tests you have that can run without WebGL you probably want to run them without osmesa.

Also note that chrome itself uses osmesa to headless test but it uses a specific version. At the time of this answer it was version 9.0.3. It also makes a few changes listed [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/mesa/README.chromium)

Otherwise to run headless in general I found this

https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747

Comment: how do you use this with selenium or nightwatch?

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. Chrome runs just fine in selenium or nightwatch so all you should need to do is install osmesa, create the sym link and then add `--use-gl=osmesa` to selenium's options for chrome. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040081/sending-command-line-parameters-to-chrome-when-selenium-node-starts

Comment: what does the no-first-run do?

Comment: It tells chrome not to do first run stuff like ask you if you want to make chrome the default browser etc... I'd assume selenium already passes that flag

Comment: how can I do the same thing but for firefox v 47.0.1 on ubuntu? do you know?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got WebGL working with docker + ubuntu + xvfb + headless chrome.

Comment: For anyone that's stumbled on this answer but get a "package not found" error, try `libosmesa6`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing docker was created for. Dealing with graphics driver installation weirdness is a full time job.