# Graphical glitches on CanvasRenderer

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Moving frm WebGL to Canvas, I encountered this graphical glitch. The code is literally the same apart from one being Canvas and the other WebGL + added:

```
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
renderer.shadowMap.cullFace = THREE.CullFaceFront;
```

Which does not work on CanvasRenderer. Does anyone know why this occur and if there is a fix with little to none code change?

**WebGLRenderer**
[image: Graphic rendered with WebGL]

**CanvasRenderer**
[image: Graphic rendered on Canvas]

Comment: AFAIK the CanvasRenderer is extremely limited in features. It doesn't support even 80s of the WebGLRenderer's features

Comment: @gman I see. So if I where to do a rendering on the server, I am forced to use CanvasRenderer and therefor limited with the features?

Comment: You can [render on the server with osmesa using WebGL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39060739/128511). It will be very slow though. There's also [headless-gl](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl). Why are you rendering on the server though?

Comment: @gman it's to secure that if it's not working on the client side (WebGL not supported) or whatever reason, we still get a snapshot of the graphic on the server for printing etc.