# Is it possible to run Three.js WebGLRenderer on node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, webgl

I am in need of running WebGLRenderer on the server, but there are different voices regarding this. Some say that it's not possible and some say they are *trying* to get it working, but that's when the discussions end.

Is it possible to do it and in that case, what is the approach? Is it possible using moch-browser combined with node-gl or something?

[edit]
Added solution

Comment: What do you plan to do with the rendered result? Stream it back to user's browser or save it to a file or ... ?

Comment: @Matey Stream it back to the user as a png.

Comment: Stream a sequence of PNGs? Or send a single PNG file?

Comment: @Matey I will stream it back to the client. I actually managed to render it. I will post a solution when I have a clean solution ready!

Comment: @JakobMillah why do you want to do server-side rendering with javascript?

Comment: @mlkn Three.js will be used to render 3D models of physical windows. A customer might order 10 different windows and we want the server to render an imaged version for each window and generate an offer file. I guess there is a reasoning behind not wanting to store a lot of images and/or security incase the rendering/three.js library not working on the client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my own solution to the problem. Depending on the size of the scene and its objects, it might take some time. In my case I want to return pretty small versions of the object, but still takes about 400ms to respond with a 400x400px png. Hope this helps someone out there!

[image]

**Server.js**

```
var THREE = require("three.js");

// Create a DOM
var MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
var mock = new MockBrowser();
var document = MockBrowser.createDocument();
var window = MockBrowser.createWindow();

//REST API
var express     = require('express');      
var app         = express();    
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

var gl = require('gl')(1,1); //headless-gl

var pngStream = require('three-png-stream');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

router.get('/render', function(req, res){

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.width / this.height, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({context:gl});

    scene.add(camera);

    renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 1);

    /*...
        Add your objects & light to the scene 
    ...*/

    var target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.width, this.height);
    renderer.render(scene, camera, target);


   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
   pngStream(renderer, target).pipe(res);
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server active on port: ' + port);
```

Comment: Would this be feasible for complex 3d animations? I imagine not... just due to network latency, but I am curious.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [headless-gl](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl) but you'd need to use some other libraries to emulate the DOM and Image tags (for texture loading) and Canvas tags and/or Canvas2D if you need that as well.

Otherwise you could [shell to a browser running on top of OSMESA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060739/128511) maybe or try [headless chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)

Comment: Yes, headless-gl was what I ended up using! That combined with mock-browser to generate the DOM. Three-png-stream to stream the rendering back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this, the trick is to render to a canvas and take out a png image object.

```js
var fs = require("fs")

var self = {};

var ratio = 16/9.0;

var canvasWidth = 500;
var canvasHeight = 500;

var window = {
    innerWidth: canvasWidth,
    innerHeight: canvasHeight

};
var document = {
    createElement: function(name) {
        if (name == "canvas") {
            //return new Canvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        }
        var Canvas = require('canvas')
        return new Canvas(500,500)
    },
    createElementNS: function(name) {

        var Canvas = require('canvas')
        return new Canvas(500,500)
    }
};

var THREE = require("./threejs/three.js")
eval(fs.readFileSync("threejs/additionalRenderers.js").toString())
eval(fs.readFileSync("threejs/SceneUtils.js").toString())

const EventEmitter = require('events');

//var OS = new ShereOS()

class ThreeClient extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super()
        var self = this
        this.appId = 667


        self.loaded = false

        this.bgColor = '#282c34'
        this.textColor = '#fff'
        this.tildeColor = '#0000ff'
        this.selectColor = '#ffffff'

        this.width = 500
        this.height = 500



        this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.width / this.height, 0.001, 3000);
        this.camera.position.z = 2;




        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xECF8FF );
        this.scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0x606060, 0x404040 ) );
        this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        this.light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
        this.scene.add( this.light );
        //console.log(this.scene.children)


        this.updated = false
        /*
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.1, 32, 32 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000} );
        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        this.scene.add( this.sphere );
        */
    }




    getTexture() {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        var data = this.renderer.domElement.toDataURL().substr("data:image/png;base64,".length)
        var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
        fs.writeFile('image.png', buf);
        //return this.renderer.domElement.toDataURL().substr("data:image/png;base64,".length);
        
    }
}

var THREEClient = new ThreeClient();
```

npm install avros

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Canvas in node.js directly. Using JSDOM or mockbrowser didn't work well for me. So, I used node-canvas library to virtuealize the canvas. After that you know what to do!

Still, here's my base snippet. Hope it helps!

```
const { createCanvas } = require("canvas");
const THREE = global.THREE = require("three");
const fs = require("fs");

async function Virtuealize_Canvas() {

    this.width = 512
    this.height = 512
    const canvas = createCanvas(this.width, this.height, { alpha: true })
    
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
    renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
    
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.width / this.height, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 11
    
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight('white', 0.8);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    const buffer = canvas.toBuffer();
    
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + `image.png`, buffer)

}
```