# Can I run A-Frame in node.js (server-side)?

Tags: node.js, aframe

I'd like to take a lot of screenshots and export .glb from thousands of generated a-frame models. Since I can't save files from the browser without prompt, generating the models on the server-side with node.js would be awesome.

(As a workaround I could probably generate the models in the browser and POST them to a local server that saves the files to disk but I'd prefer the server-side rendering if possible)

So, how can I render A-Frame models in node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried approaches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736134/is-it-possible-to-run-three-js-webglrenderer-on-node-js-server) with [mock-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser) for mocking the DOM (which is necessary in `three`, let alone DOM-based `a-frame`) and [headless-gl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/headless-gl) for creating a WebGL context in node.

No luck there, so I settled with an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) application.

tldr: [check this out](https://github.com/gftruj/electro-aframe). Download, `npm install; npm run start;` and render screenshots / export the scene as glb. If you like it, let me know how to improve it to make it more useful.

---

non tldr:

You can load up an `a-frame` website using electron, but use the main process to save the screenshot on your drive - so there are no prompts, and it can be automated.

To make a render, You can simply use the native [screenshot](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/screenshot.html#sidebar) component to create a canvas containing the screenshot image

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.getCanvas('equirectangular');
```

but instead of downloading the blob, pass it into the main process via an [renderer to main IPC channel](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) - where you can save it on your drive.

Comment: awesome, it works! (had to add express as dep and had to create output folder by hand). reading the source code right now but I'll be able to do this with your demo. thanks a lot! 

Comment: Glad you like it - It's quite simple, but I think I could expand it if you think it could be useful. Also I've updated the things you mentioned - added `express` - weird that it worked for me, as for the output folder - it should create it upon launch now