# webGL dependent application in opening in chrome

Tags: selenium, opengl-es, webgl

I have a situation here that we have a webGL dependent application to automate. i have automated the whole application on my laptop, and this application is running fine on chrome on my laptop. but the issue is when i run this application from a seperate machine which is a selenium GRID node. It gives me a message that the application required Webgl and and it ask me to enable the webGL. i have tried different methods like selenium option and ignoring the chrome black list as well.

when i open the browser manually and open the application it runs find and i checked on url chrome://gpu. it shows that the gpu is enaled.

but when i invoke the selenium and run the test cases,. the browser initiates with WebGl as disabled

Comment: I see you found a solution. For people that want to run on a machine without a GPU there's [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39060739)

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution to this. here is the code you can use to enable WebGL for chrome.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        **options.addArguments("--ignore-gpu-blacklist");**
        capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capability.setCapability("chrome.binary", "C:\\Temp\\chromedriver.exe");
        capability.setVersion("9999");

        capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        return new RemoteWebDriver(HUB_URL,capability);
```