# How do I emulate WebGL stuff with OESMesa on AWS Lambda?

Tags: selenium, lambda, webgl, e2e-testing

I would like to take a screenshot of a web site using WebGL. I don't have to use GPU to open that site. Using emulation is enough for me.

At the beginning, I already tried headless-chrome to do this. That can take screenshot of ordinal web sites. But, It not works for WebGL canvases.
I think one of possibility is using OSMesa or something to emulate OpenGL.

I have used all of my strategy for overcoming this. Is this actually possible to do?
If yes, please tell me how to do that. If no, I would like to know why.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of what exactly, and from "where" ? I a m tempted to answere: if you want to take a screenshot, check-out your OS API for screen buffer data access, no matter OpenGL, WebGL or Mesa... to answere your question: To emulate WebGL (OpenGL ES 2.0) using Mesa, if OESMesa is what i think, maybe starting here ? : https://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html

Comment: [Is this the answer you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040370/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu)?

Comment: @Sedenion Thank you for replying. I would like to use AWS lambda to take screenshot of my webpages that use WebGL stuff a lot. I hit OSMesa also, but I have no idea to use that on lambda.

Comment: @gman yes, I can use that on my own Ubuntu env. However, because of lambda limitation, I don't think I cant run yum command. I have to build them on EC2 container to use it on lambda. But, I have no idea what should I configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

You need the right combination of:

1. headless-chromium binary
2. libosmesa.os binary (in same directory)
3. launch chrome headless with the right flags, such as (see link for full details): `['--use-gl=osmesa', '--enable-webgl', '--ignore-gpu-blacklist', '--homedir=/tmp', '--single-process', '--data-path=/tmp/data-path', '--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir']`

This thread on the serverless-chrome github project discusses the issue and provides some binaries which I have used to capture screenshots of WebGL content on AWS Lambda using Page.captureScreenshot().

https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/108#issuecomment-416494572

(See comment by @apalchys on 28th August)

This particular example uses [SwiftShader](https://swiftshader.googlesource.com/SwiftShader) which seems to be the preferred option going forward.

Note, however, that I was unable to create PDFs using `Page.printToPDF()` using this version - WebGL content just appears blank/white. However, I was able to also get `Page.printToPDF()` using an earlier version which uses osmesa, see https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/108#issuecomment-371199530

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer! This is what I wanted to. Thanks a lot.