# Unable to render WebGL in Electron with Xvfb

Tags: linux, electron, webgl, mapbox-gl, xvfb

I am trying to render my app which has a WebGL dependency in Electron on my Linux PC, but nothing is rendering on the page, except for the CSS background color. When I remove the WebGL dependency, which is MapboxGL, then everything renders normally.

I am using X Virtual Frame Buffer, which seems necessary for a Linux environment, as described here: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-on-headless-ci

I am running Xvfb using this command:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > xvfblog.txt 2>&1 &
```

And then I start my app with the prefix:

```
DISPLAY=:99
```

so that the app connects to the X Virtual Frame Buffer display.

I am not sure if this is relevant, but Xvfb starts up with the following messages:

> The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
>
> > Warning:          Unsupported high keycode 372 for name  ignored
>
> >                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
>
> >                   This warning only shows for the first high keycode.
>
> > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86WWAN
>
> > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86RFKill
>
> > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86Keyboard
>
> Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server

I also noticed that when I test my app using Electron on a Macbook, Xvfb is not required, and my WebGL app renders just fine.

I am a bit stumped here. Are there any suggestions about what could be wrong, or what I can investigate for a fix?

Comment: You need to [add the chromium command line options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches) inside your Electron app I think but this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040370/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by configuring Xvfb to work with WebGL as follows:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension GLX +render > xvfblog.txt 2>&1 &
```

Where I added the `+extension GLX +render` flags.

I also had to start electron with the `ignore-gpu-blacklist` flag. I found this article helpful with that: https://medium.com/social-tables-tech/how-we-test-webgl-on-continuous-integration-37a1ead55fd7

Also note that I am using the "electron" npm package, and I had to add the following flags to my `BrowserWindow` object:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    webgl: true,
    webSecurity: false,
    experimentalFeatures: true,
    experimentalCanvasFeatures: true,
    offscreen: true
  }
})
```

I hope this helps someone.